# Postgres: delete rows order by without primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I would like to delete most recent insert up to "n" rows.

For example:

```
DELETE FROM users 
WHERE user_id = %s AND group_id = %s 
ORDER BY message_date DESC
```

I understood it's a syntax error and searching on the web I found many stackoverflow answers telling to use a form like

```
DELETE FROM users 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id ....)
```

Unfortunately I don't have a primary key on that table, they are just inserts without an auto increment.

How can I do it?

Maybe I should something like

```
WITH t AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM users 
    WHERE user_id = %s AND group_id = %s 
    ORDER BY message_date DESC
) 
DELETE FROM t
```

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt the code you found using ids:

```
DELETE users u
    WHERE u.user_id = %s AND u.group_id = %s AND
          u.message_date IN (SELECT u2.message_date
                             FROM users u2
                             WHERE u2.user_id = u.user_id AND
                                   u2.group_id = u.group_id
                             ORDER BY u2.message_date DESC
                             LIMIT <n>
                            );
```

I hope you have learned from this how useful serial primary keys can be in a database.

Note:  This can delete more than  rows, if there are ties in the database.

EDIT:

Let me add, I would be more inclined to approach this as:

```
DELETE users u
    FROM (SELECT u2.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, group_id ORDER BY message_date DESC) as seqnum
          FROM users u2
         ) u2
         ON u2.user_id = u.user_id AND u2.group_id = u.group_id AND
            u2.message_date = u.message_date
     WHERE u.user_id = %s AND u.group_id = %s AND
           seqnum <= <n>;
```

This ensures that exactly  rows are deleted, even with ties.

Comment: Yes. In fact I asked that question to consider to add the serial primary key

Answer (score 4):

If your table doesn't have any serial IDs (for example if there is an existing multi-column primary key) you can still use `IN` to filter the rows you want to delete:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE (key1, key2) IN (
    SELECT key1, key2 FROM table_name ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2
);
```

For your specific case you can use:

```
DELETE FROM users 
WHERE (user_id, group_id) IN (
    SELECT user_id, group_id FROM users
    WHERE user_id = %s AND group_id = %s
    ORDER BY message_date DESC
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no candidate key to order by,you can always use ctid: (guaranteed to be unique)

---

```
DELETE FROM one
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM one x
        WHERE x.oneseq <= 3 -- whatever condition
        AND x.ctid = one.ctid
        ORDER BY x.ctid
        LIMIT 3 -- number of rows you want todelete
        );
```

---

This will work with `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY...ORDER BY ctid) as rn`, too. (which of course is nonsensical,since the `ctid` order will be *more or less* random anyway)